# libboost error during linking

Tags: ros, message, libboost, synchronization, approximatetime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
Linking CXX executable ../bin/msg_synch
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/msg_synch.dir/src/msg_synch.o: undefined reference to symbol 'boost::signals::connection::~connection()'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'boost::signals::connection::~connection()' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_signals.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libboost_signals.so.1.46.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The above error occurs when I try to compile test code for approximate time synchronization. The boost library exists and is found, however, I can not interpret the error...other than the obvious, which does not work, adding the lib to the linker. Any suggestions?

As in a previous question, I am synching 3 separate messages with time stamped headers.
[link text](http://answers.ros.org/question/52178/synchronizing-3-messages-build-errors/)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52632/libboost-error-during-linking/) by [101010](https://answers.ros.org/users/3108/101010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 79 on 2013-01-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-02-04**:
How are you linking your executable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
# Put this line before the executable or library in your CMakeLists.txt
   rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
   # assuming that my_target is your executable
   rosbuild_add_executable(my_target my_srcs/my_target.cpp)
   # Put this line after the executable or library:
   rosbuild_link_boost(my_target signals)
```

source : http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Migration

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0